# Nativescript submission to Apple Store fails with ERROR ITMS-90034

Tags: ios, nativescript, sidekick

When publishing to App Store from Nativescript Sidekick I get the following error:

Error: Spawn failed. [Transporter Error Output]: Sign in with the app-specific password you generated. If you forgot the app-specific password or need to create a new one, go to appleid.apple.com (-22938) [Transporter Error Output]: ERROR ITMS-90034: "Missing or invalid signature. The bundle '*****' at bundle path 'Payload/*****.app' is not signed using an Apple submission certificate."

I tried to renew certificate and provisioning profile but it doesn't solve.
What to do?

Comment: Did you double check the app specific password, is it correct? Does the account have credentials to upload apps?

Comment: Yes, the account have credentials to upload apps and I checked the two factor authentication first and the app specific password double. On the app store connect, the app results as "In preparazione per l'invio" but upload of the build fails.